# How can I create a huge xml (> 2GB) starting from a base xml

Tags: java, xml, sax, stax

I need to develop some functionality in order to do some load testing. The goal of the functionality is to create a xml (size > 2 GB) based on an existing xml. The xml defines documents and collections (of documents). Each document and collection contains a lot of tags defining the document/collection. The base xml is about 100 kb. It contains 2 documents and one collection. Based on this xml, I would like to create a new xml. In the resulting xml, the collections and documents should be copied a number of times (up to 100.000).

A small calculation shows that the resulting xml might have a size of bigger then 2 GB. I'm afraid this excludes DOM parsing.

The base xml has the following format (this is not the result xml, but its structure is similar)):

```
<request attribute1="xxx" attribute2="yyy">
<element1>...</element1>
<element2>...</element2>
<documents>
  <document>
    <documentReference></documentReference>
    <documentElement1></documentElement1>
    <documentElement2></documentElement2>
    <documentElement3></documentElement3>
    ... (document contains a lot of information (element tags))
  </document>
  <document>
    <documentReference></documentReference>
    <documentElement1></documentElement1>
    <documentElement2></documentElement2>
    <documentElement3></documentElement3>
    ... (document contains a lot of information (element tags))
  </document>
</documents>
<collections>
  <collection>
    <collectionReference></collectionReference>
    <collectionElement1></collectionElement1>
    <collectionElement2></collectionElement2>
    <collectionElement3></collectionElement3>
    <documents>
      <document>
        <documentReference></documentReference>
        <someTagDefiningTheDocument1>...</someTagDefiningTheDocument1>
        <someTagDefiningTheDocument2>...</someTagDefiningTheDocument2>
      </document>
    </documents>
  </collection>
</collections>
</request>
```

In the above xml, the collections and documents need to be copied many times (up to 100.000). The only values that need to be updated in the copies are the references. The document tag contains a lot of data, but the collection tag is rather small.
My thinking was to do this in two steps:

1. copy collections
2. save resulting xml: resulting xml is basic xml + copied collections in xml
3. Use resulting xml and copy documents

As the result xml will be huge (2 GB), I used stax parser to copy the collection as many times I want. That work was doable. The end result is an xml, containing a given number of collections and saved in a given directory. The result is fine. So step 1 and 2 are done.
Following is an example of how I added the collection elements using stax parser:

```
public static final String LEGAL_ENTITY_NAMESPACE = "http://some/name/space";

public void populate(XMLEventWriter writer, int indent) {
    Address address = AddressBuilder.builder().build();
    QName addressQName = new QName(LEGAL_ENTITY_NAMESPACE, "address");
    writer.setDefaultNamespace(LEGAL_ENTITY_NAMESPACE);
    createStartElement(writer, addressQName, Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), indent);
    createElement(writer, new QName(LEGAL_ENTITY_NAMESPACE, "street"), address.getStreet(), indent + 1);
    createElement(writer, new QName(LEGAL_ENTITY_NAMESPACE, "houseNumber"), address.getHouseNumber(), indent + 1);
    createElement(writer, new QName(LEGAL_ENTITY_NAMESPACE, "boxNumber"), address.getBoxNumber(), indent + 1);
    populatorHelper.createElement(writer, new QName(LEGAL_ENTITY_NAMESPACE, "city"), address.getCity(), indent + 1);
    createElement(writer, new QName(LEGAL_ENTITY_NAMESPACE, "zipcode"), address.getZipcode(), indent + 1);
    createEndElement(writer, addressQName, indent);
}

public void createStartElement(XMLEventWriter writer, QName element, Optional<Iterator<Attribute>> attributes,
        Optional<Iterator<Namespace>> nameSpaces, int indent) {
    addEndAndTabs(writer, indent);
    writer.add(eventFactory.createStartElement(element, attributes.orElse(null), nameSpaces.orElse(null)));
}

public void createElement(XMLEventWriter writer, QName element, String value, int indent) {
    addEndAndTabs(writer, indent);
    writer.add(eventFactory.createStartElement(element, null, null));
    writer.add(eventFactory.createCharacters(value));
    writer.add(eventFactory.createEndElement("", "", element.getLocalPart()));
}

public void createEndElement(XMLEventWriter writer, QName element, int indent) {
    addEndAndTabs(writer, indent);
    writer.add(eventFactory.createEndElement("", "", element.getLocalPart()));
}
```

The above code is a sample of how the collections are added to the new xml. There is more code involved off course. This works fine. The result I have now is an xml, basic on the base xml, with a huge number of collections.

I still have to do the third step: copy the documents (with all its content) and update the documentReference.
However, with stax I need to create every tag. As a document in the xml is over 1000 lines (with a lot of information describing the document), this is not doable. So I was wondering if it is possible to copy the complete document tag (with all it's content) in the resulting xml.

Summary:

- A base xml (posted xml above) is used to generate an xml.
- Using stax parser, a result xml was created based on the above basic xml. The result xml already contains the copied collections (sample code above).
- the resulting xml (with the copied collections) are saved in a directory (xml = 250 MB).
- next step: copy the documents. Remember: the document tags contain a lot of data. End result will be a xml of 2 GB.
- The end result should be a xml, based on the basic xml (posted above), containing a huge number of documents and collections.

Questions:

1. Because of the size of the resulting xml, is the choice for stax parsing ok?
2. How can I copy the complete document tag in xml, taking into account that the end result will be a huge xml?

Comment: Possibly because you are discussing in generalities, your question is unclear. Can you set up a specific problem: 1. input XML, 2. attempted code, 3. desired output? It is unclear how you are updating the XML. Is the posted XML the result of your Java code to add `collectionElements`?

Comment: Hi @Parfait, I updated the description above. To answer on your questions: 1. input XML = xml posted in the ticket, 2. attempted code = code posted above (but only used to copy the collection), 3. desired output = now I also need to copy the documents (starting from the resulting xml with the copied collections)? Be aware that the posted XML is the base XML. But the resulting xml will have a similar structure, but with a number of copied collections and documents.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose, declarative language to transform XML files to other XML, HTML, even text files. With this approach, you can simply copy needed elements in existing XML and avoid manually rebuilding tree in Java with DOM methods.

Because XSLT is its own language, it is portable. Below is a `javax.xml` implementation but consider [Xalan](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html) or [Saxon](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/about/gettingstarted/gettingstartedjava.html) command line tools available in Java libraries and may help with large file outputs. Specifically, XSLT runs the identity transform to copy document as is and then in *collections*, copies its child *collection* for needed number of iterations (here at 5). See [XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7nv/1) using Saxon HE.

**XSLT 1.0** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file, to be referenced in Java)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="collections">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection" mode="iter">
        <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="5"/>          <!-- ADJUST NUMBER OF ITERATIONS -->
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="collection" mode="iter">
      <xsl:param name="pCount"/>
      <xsl:if test="$pCount > 0">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="iter">
            <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="$pCount -1"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Java**

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class XSLTransform_JAVA {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException,
                                                  SAXException, ParserConfigurationException,
                                                  TransformerException {

            // Load XML and XSL Document
            String inputXML = "/path/to/Input.xml";
            String xslFile = "/path/to/XSLT_Script.xsl";
            String outputXML = "/path/to/Output.xml";

            Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File(xslFile));            
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();            
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File(inputXML));

            // XSLT Transformation with pretty print
            TransformerFactory prettyPrint = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = prettyPrint.newTransformer(xslt);

            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");                        

            // Output Result to File
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(outputXML));        
            transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
}
```

---

[Xalan command line](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html)

```
java org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -IN source.xml -XSL script.xsl -OUT output.xml
```

[Saxon command line](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/using-xsl/commandline.html)

```
java net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:source.xml -xsl:script.xsl -o:output.xml

java -jar dir/saxon9he.jar -s:source.xml -xsl:script.xsl -o:output.xml
```

[Other XSLT tools...](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info)